# How to turn off interpolation in pcolormesh()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've noticed pcolormesh by default interpolates/smoothes the raw data. How do I turn this off?

Comment: `pcolormesh` doesn't interpolate at all. It produces vector rectangles, so it can't do any type of interpolation.  Are you thinking of `imshow`?  If so, specify `interpolation='none'` or `"nearest"`.

Comment: @JoeKington No I'm thinking of pcolormesh. When I plot the same data in some other software it seems less "smoothed". Perhaps it is the result of the color map, then.

Comment: matplotlib with apply antialiasing to the edges of the vector rectangles.  (This is a very different thing than interpolation.)  `plt.imshow(data, interpolation='none')` is probably much closer to what the software you're comparing to does.  Regardless, it sounds like you're plotting a large image.  `imshow` is a better choice, in that case.  There's no need for a vector representation of each pixel, and `imshow` will be much faster.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks for your answer, I guess the question is invalid and I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not invalid. `pcolor` and `pcolormesh` are certainly interpolating!

Use `pcolor` to plot a 4x4 matrix and you will get a 3x3 output.
`pcolor` is not plotting each matrix entry, but each "output value" is an interpolation of the four surrounding values of the original matrix.

And there is no way to turn this off.